# Liferay6.2 : DisplayTag in Struts2 - "Nothing to display"

Tags: java, jsp, struts2, liferay, displaytag

Here is my problem :
I'm using a Liferay 6.2, with Struts2 
I want to use DisplayTag for pagination, but the table doesn't appears, and Liferay shows me this message "**Nothing found to display**."

I need to show 3 students in a HTML Table :

I put all of the code (bellow) in a simple and classic "Dynamic Web Project" with a Tomcat7, and I can see my 3 students.

But here, with Liferay, I've got the message "**Nothing to display.**"

*Web.xml :*

```
<web-app [...]>
    <display-name>HelloStruts</display-name>
    <display-name>Struts 2 Web Application</display-name>
    <filter>
        <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter</filter-class>
    </filter>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>
</web-app>
```

*Struts.xml :*

```
<struts>
    <constant name="struts.devMode" value="true" />
    <package namespace="/view" extends="struts-portlet-default" name="view">
        <action name="viewDisplayTags" class="com.displaytags.StudentAction" method="fetchStudentList">
            <result name="success">/html/displaytags/viewDisplayTags.jsp</result>
        </action>
    </package>
</struts>
```

*StudentAction.java :*

```
public class StudentAction extends ActionSupport {
    private List<StudentBean> students = new ArrayList<StudentBean>();

    public String fetchStudentList() {
        students.add(new StudentBean("o7bb002", "Ajay"));
        students.add(new StudentBean("o7bc055", "Mohiadeen"));
        students.add(new StudentBean("o7bc074", "Sriram Ganesh"));

        return SUCCESS;
    }

    public List<StudentBean> getStudents() {
        return students;
    }

    public void setStudents(List<StudentBean> students)     {
        this.students = students;
    }
}
```

*StudentBean.java*

```
public class StudentBean {

    private String rollNo;
    private String studentName;

    public StudentBean(String rollNo, String studentName)  {
        this.rollNo = rollNo;
        this.studentName = studentName;
    }

    public String getRollNo() {
        return rollNo;
    }

    public void setRollNo(String rollNo) {
        this.rollNo = rollNo;
    }

    public String getStudentName()  {
        return studentName;
    }

    public void setStudentName(String studentName)  {
        this.studentName = studentName;
    }
}
```

*viewDisplayTags.jsp*

```
<%@taglib prefix="s" uri="/struts-tags" %>
<%@ include file="/html/init.jsp" %>
<%@ include file="headerDisplayTags.jspf" %>

<%@ taglib prefix="display" uri="http://displaytag.sf.net"%>

<s:hidden name="studentsHiddenList" value="%{students}" />

<display:table name="students">
    <display:column property="rollNo" title="Roll No" sortable="true"></display:column>
    <display:column property="studentName" title="Student Name" sortable="true" ></display:column>
</display:table>
```

That's strange, because with the content of the "hidden" (in "*viewDisplayTags.jsp*") I can see my 3 students ... The Students List is transmitted from the Java Class to the JSP

Thank you !

Answer (score 0):

I've finally found the answer :

The List "*Students*" wasn't in the "request" and the attribute *class* and *requestURI* in "" wasn't set correctly

*StudentAction.java :*

```
public class StudentAction extends ActionSupport {
    private List<StudentBean> students = new ArrayList<StudentBean>();

    public String fetchStudentList() {
        students.add(new StudentBean("o7bb002", "Ajay"));
        students.add(new StudentBean("o7bc055", "Mohiadeen"));
        students.add(new StudentBean("o7bc074", "Sriram Ganesh"));

        Map request = (Map) ActionContext.getContext().get("request");
        request.put("students",students);

        return SUCCESS;
    }

    public List<StudentBean> getStudents()  {
        return students;
    }

    public void setStudents(List<StudentBean> students)  {
        this.students = students;
    }
}
```

*viewDisplayTags.jsp*

```
<%@taglib prefix="s" uri="/struts-tags" %>
<%@ include file="/html/init.jsp" %>
<%@ include file="headerDisplayTags.jspf" %>

<%@ taglib prefix="display" uri="http://displaytag.sf.net"%>

<s:hidden name="studentsHiddenList" value="%{students}" />

<display:table name="students" class="StudentAction" requestURI="/viewDisplayTags.jsp">
    <display:column property="rollNo" title="Roll No" sortable="true"></display:column>
    <display:column property="studentName" title="Student Name" sortable="true" ></display:column>
</display:table>
```

Comment: mmno, it's not that, this is a workaround...just user requestURI and id in the page and #attr. to access request data from displaytag: http://www.simplecodestuffs.com/struts-2-tag-not-working-inside-a-display-tag-solution/